# can we increase the emulator's rom size for loading large applications

Tags: android, android-emulator

For running my application in emulator, is it possible to increase the rom size for emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can run large applications too in emulator.

Inside eclipse, `Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android -> Launch -> default emulator options` 
give `-partition-size 1024`